# Approximation of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{T_k}$ where $T_k$ are the tribonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

So I have heard about the reciprocal Fibonacci constant, which is the sum of the reciprocals of the Fibonacci numbers. A natural question is to ask what we get when we add the reciprocals of the Tribonacci numbers $T_k$ (which satisfy the recurrence relation $T_k=T_{k-1}+T_{k-2}+T_{k-3}$ and $T_0=0$ and $T_1=T_2=1$). I tried to put $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{T_k}$ into Wolfram Alpha but it says that this diverges. Of course that's just absurd since the Tribonacci numbers grow quicker than the Fibonacci numbers. My question is, may you help give me an approximation of this constant up to $3$ decimal digits? I don't have any advanced math software like Mathematica. And is my claim that the sum converges true? My only reason why this converges is the fact that it *seems* that the Tribonacci numbers grow quicker than the Fibonacci numbers, which seems obvious but I don't know for sure.

Thanks for reading the whole post!

Comment: The tribonacci numbers grow exponentially quickly, so yes, it converges.  It is not hard to give an explicit formula for tribonacci numbers using the same machinery that leads to Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers; that will give you the base of the exponent (the limit of $(T_n)^{1/n}$), which according to http://oeis.org/A000073 is larger than 1.8.  It follows that you only need about 15 terms to get it exact to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Also, yes, you can easily prove by (strong) induction that $T_n \geq F_n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be shown that
$$ \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{T_{k}} < \frac{1}{T_{n} - T_{n-1} - 1}, $$
which, for $n>4$, works well. Now, for $n>0$, the sum takes the form
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{T_{k}} < \frac{1}{T_{1}} + \frac{1}{T_{2}} + \frac{1}{T_{3}} + \frac{1}{T_{4}} + \frac{1}{T_{5} - T_{4} - 1} = 3.25. $$
This can be partially found in the article by [Anantakitpaisal and Kuhapatanakul](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL19/Kuhapatanakul/kuha7.html).

Numerically the value of the sum is
$$3.0612290851054928774253826071147789249412794648974344700718107630658978210...$$
which, for this case, was obtained from Sagemath by use of the code

```
@CachedFunction
def T(n): # Tribonacci numbers
    if (n<3): return (0,1,1)[n]
    else: return T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)
@CachedFunction
def S(n): return 1/T(1) if (n==1) else 1/T(n) + S(n-1)
numerical_approx(S(400), digits=100)
```

which can be run in SageCell at [SageCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org). Note that on the Sagecell site, by changing the language setting to Python, the code in another answer can also be run to obtain the numerical value by use of Python.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the sum does converge, we can write up a little Python script to approximate the value (Thanks to Calvin Khor and G Cab for the improvements):

```
a, b, c = 0, 1, 1
s = 2

for _ in range(1000):
    a, b, c = b, c, a + b + c
    s += 1 / c

print(s)
```

We see that the sum of the first $1002$ terms is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{T_k} \approx\sum_{k=1}^{1002}\frac{1}{T_k} \approx 3.061229085105492
$$

Comment: if $T_1= T_2 = 1$ you shall get more than 2

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected this

Comment: Since we don't need to compute the entire sequence, you can instead update the triple e.g. : `a, b, c = 0, 1, 1`,
`s = 2`, then in the loop
    `a, b, c = b, c, a + b + c` and
    `s += 1 / c`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've made the changes. Looks like I default to memoization when it comes to computing sequences...