# Analytic continuation of the sum of the reciprocals of the $n$-bonacci sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, graphing-functions, fibonacci-numbers, analytic-continuation

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4591700/approximation-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1t-k-where-t-k-are-the-tribonacc), I asked for an approximation of the sum of the reciprocals of the Tribonacci numbers. So I was wondering if there is a function for the sum of the reciprocals of the $n$-bonacci numbers. This would look like this: $$\varkappa(n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{N_{n_k}}$$ Where $N_n$ gives the $n$-bonacci sequence ($n=1$ gives $1, 1, 1, ...$, $n=2$ gives the fibonacci sequence, $n=3$ gives the tribonacci sequence, and so on). I graphed the first four points in this desmos [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s8k5a95g78). So what function could connect these points? And additionally, does $\varkappa$ have a lower bound? What is it? (I suspect it is $1.5$ or something near but I couldn't prove this.

Comment: In order to better understand the value of  $2.43$ which appears on your graph, could you precise which are for you the first Tetrabonacii numbers. Are they $$\{1,1,2,4,8,15,29,56,108,208,401,773,1490\}$$ or $$\{1,2,4,8,15,29,56,108,208,401,773,1490,2872\}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You mean Tribonacci. I chose the first one.

Comment: Non ! Tetrabonacci

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh, sorry about that. Yes, I chose the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function of the standard $n$-bonacci numbers being
$$f_n(x)=\frac{ x^{n-1}}{1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^k}=\frac{(1-x)\, x^{n-1}}{x^{n+1}-2 x+1}$$

the sum of their reciprocals $S_n$ write
$$S_n=3+\epsilon_n$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \epsilon_n & \log(\epsilon_n) \\
 2 & 0.35988566624317755317 & -1.0220 \\
 3 & 0.06122908510549287743 & -2.7931 \\
 4 & 0.01325565493979152335 & -4.3233 \\
 5 & 0.00310889227803160293 & -5.7735 \\
 6 & 0.00075409134353350541 & -7.1900 \\
 7 & 0.00018577050528064920 & -8.5910 \\
 8 & 0.00004610682714077771 & -9.9845 \\
 9  & 0.00001148523413006498 & -11.374 \\
 10 & 0.00000286615546739387 & -12.763 \\
 11 & 0.00000071589666140425 & -14.150 \\
 12 & 0.00000017889400983734 & -15.536 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

A quick and dirty linear regression based on the data for $3 \leq n \leq 25$
$$\log(\epsilon_n)=a-b\,n$$ gives, with $R^2=0.999994$,

$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & 1.19140 & 0.02474 & \{1.13996,1.24284\} \\
 b & 1.39135 & 0.00160 & \{1.38803,1.39467\} \\
\end{array}$$